# Restructure a JSON and output to another file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm getting a very long list of one level json data that look something like this:
***json-old.json***

```
[
{"stock": "abc", "volume": "45434", "price": "31", "date": "10/12/12"},
{"stock": "abc", "volume": "45435", "price": "30", "date": "10/13/12"},
{"stock": "xyz", "volume": "34465", "price": "14", "date": "10/12/12"},
{"stock": "xyz", "volume": "34434", "price": "14", "date": "10/13/12"},
{"stock": "zzz", "volume": "76755", "price": "65", "date": "10/12/12"},
{"stock": "zzz", "volume": "85646", "price": "67", "date": "10/13/12"}
]
```

how can I take that above file and output it to a new file: 
***json-new.json***

```
[
{ 
   "abc": {
      "10/12/12": { "volume": "45434", "price": "31" },
      "10/13/12": { "volume": "45435", "price": "30" }
   }
},
{
   "xyz": {
      "10/12/12": { "volume": "34465", "price": "14" },
      "10/13/12": { "volume": "34434", "price": "14" }
   }
},
{
   "zzz": {
      "10/12/12": { "volume": "76755", "price": "65" },
      "10/13/12": { "volume": "85646", "price": "67" }
   }
}
]
```

Basically I want to organize and nest the data under the 'stock' property, and then nest the remaining data under 'date' property.

Is there a library I can use to automate this process in javascript or nodejs? I have a lot of this files inside a folder and want to output it to single file with the desired output (so that I can upload to a database like firebase).

Comment: Hi Gab, please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi @FarooqKhan, to be perfectly honest, I don't even know where to start. I'm only a beginner in javascript and suddenly I get this task. I just want someone to point me in the right direction, and look and try to solve from there.

Comment: Ok as a push, you should  be grouping your data based on `stock` and `date` to get  your desired result.

Comment: [lodash](https://lodash.com) provides some useful functions, please read its docs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use for loop as follow.

```js
var arr = [
        { "stock": "abc", "volume": "45434", "price": "31", "date": "10/12/12" },
        { "stock": "abc", "volume": "45435", "price": "30", "date": "10/13/12" },
        { "stock": "xyz", "volume": "34465", "price": "14", "date": "10/12/12" },
        { "stock": "xyz", "volume": "34434", "price": "14", "date": "10/13/12" },
        { "stock": "zzz", "volume": "76755", "price": "65", "date": "10/12/12" },
        { "stock": "zzz", "volume": "85646", "price": "67", "date": "10/13/12" }
    ];
    var group = [];
    var json = []
    for (var item in arr)
    {
        var itm=arr[item];
        var date = {
            'volume': itm.volume,
            'price': itm.price
        }
        var stock = group[itm.stock] || {};
        stock[itm.date] = date;
        group[itm.stock] = stock;
    }
    for (i in group) {
        var obj = {}
        obj[i] = group[i];
        json.push(obj)
    }
    console.log(json);
   // console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

and you use json as new format

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const s = [
    { "stock": "abc", "volume": "45434", "price": "31", "date": "10/12/12" },
    { "stock": "abc", "volume": "45435", "price": "30", "date": "10/13/12" },
    { "stock": "xyz", "volume": "34465", "price": "14", "date": "10/12/12" },
    { "stock": "xyz", "volume": "34434", "price": "14", "date": "10/13/12" },
    { "stock": "zzz", "volume": "76755", "price": "65", "date": "10/12/12" },
    { "stock": "zzz", "volume": "85646", "price": "67", "date": "10/13/12" }
]

const g = s.reduce((ret, o) => {
    const {stock, date, ...props} = o

    const items = ret[stock] || {}
    items[date] = props
    ret[stock] = items

    return ret
}, {})

console.log([g])
```

Comment: Thank you. Clean and concise solution! Now I'll look for a way to accept the initial data from multiple files and output it to one file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
const fs = require('fs')

const groupBy = (items, key) => items.reduce(
    (result, item) => ({
      ...result,
      [item[key]]: [
        ...(result[item[key]] || []),
        item,
      ],
    }), 
    {},
);

const inFileName = process.argv[2]
const outFileName = process.argv[3]

const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(inFileName, 'utf8'));
const groupedStock = groupBy(json,'stock')
const groupedDate = {}
for(s in groupedStock)
    groupedDate[s] = groupBy(groupedStock[s],'date')

const filtered = {}
for(s in groupedDate){
    filtered[s] = {}
    for (d in groupedDate[s]) {
        filtered[s][d] = {
            price: groupedDate[s][d][0].price,
            volume: groupedDate[s][d][0].volume
        }
    }
}

const res = []
for(s in filtered)
    res.push({
        [s]: filtered[s]
    })


fs.writeFileSync(outFileName, JSON.stringify(res,null,2));
```

Run the program using `node convert.js json-old.json json-new.json`

Comment: Hey thanks man. This achieved what I was looking for. I couldn't ask you for more, but I still need to update this code to accept multiple files from a folder then output it to one file. I'll study more about the node file system module that you used here. Thanks!